# How do smooth when scrolling group? - livecode

Tags: livecode

I want to do smooth when scrolling group.In group have three image.I want to make slideshow.

When I scrolling group and release it.I want it has smooth.

Here my code:

```
local sScrolling
local sInitialMouseX, sInitialMouseY
local sInitialHScroll, sInitialVScroll

on mouseDown
   ## Allow the group to scroll
   put true into sScrolling

   ## Record the initial touch position
   put item 1 of the mouseLoc into sInitialMouseX
   put item 2 of the mouseLoc into sInitialMouseY

   ## Record the initial hScroll and vScroll
   put the vScroll of me into sInitialVScroll
   put the hScroll of me into sInitialHScroll
end mouseDown

on mouseMove mouseX, mouseY
   ## If the screen is being touched then
   if sScrolling then      
      ## Calculate how far the touch has moved since it started
      put mouseY - sInitialMouseY into tVChange
      put mouseX- sInitialMouseX into tHChange

      ## Reset the hScroll and vScroll to follow the touch
      lock screen
      set the vScroll of me to sInitialVScroll - tVChange
      set the hScroll of me to sInitialHScroll - tHChange
      put the hScroll of me into lastPoint
      unlock screen
   end if
end mouseMove

on mouseRelease
   mouseUp
end mouseRelease

on mouseUp
   put false into sScrolling
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at your code in more detail I couldn't comment on the algorithm to perform the actual moving. I would suggest using the acceleratedRendering feature though which instructs LiveCode to cache the contents of your group so rendering is much faster.

```
on preOpenStack
  set the acceleratedRendering to true
end preOpenStack
```

The above code turns the feature on. The accelerated rendering feature in LiveCode causes the engine to render your stack in small tiles which are cached. The GPU (graphics chip) is responsible for compositing all these tiles together each time the operating system refreshes the screen (roughly 60 frames per second on iOS for example). If the tile hasn't changed, the GPU simply displays it.. if something has changed, i.e you move a controls, the tiles covering that control are redrawn.

To help LiveCode cache correctly, you need to give it some information about the controls on your card and what they represent. You do this by setting the layerMode. It can be one of three options:

1. static (Default) - The control doesn't move or change
2. dynamic - The control is either moving or changing
3. scrolling (groups only) - The group contains content that is being scrolled

So in your case I would do the following also:

```
set the layerMode of group "scrollingGroup" to "scrolling"
```

Give that a try, it should speed up rendering making it easier for your to write a nice smooth transition between your images.